# How to fadein jquery background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, background, fadein

I am first time JQuery user today. I have managed to figure out how to work it enough to do what I want, which is change the color of the background onhover of button.

Only problem is that there is no fadein effect. I have looked up the fadein function but am not sure how to implement it into what I have done so far because the syntax is very different from what I am used to. Can anyone help me figure out how to add the fadein function to my code?

Thanks! Looking forward to replies! :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>index.html</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bgcolor.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class='splash'>

    <div id='logoblock'>
        <img src='images/logo.png'>
    </div>

    <div id='menublock'>
        <a href='#' id='jabout'><div id='about'></div></a>
        <a href='#' id='jphoto'><div id='photo'></div></a>
        <a href='#' id='jinfo' ><div id='info'></div></a>
    </div>

    <div id='quoteblock'
        <p class=quote>"blah blah blah!"</p>
        <p class=author>- John Doe</p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

bgcolor.js

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#jphoto" ).hover(
    function() {
        $('body').css('background', '#9dd5fc');
    },
    function() {
        $('body').css('background', '#d4e88f');
    }   
);

$( "#jabout" ).hover(
    function() {
        $('body').css('background', '#ffaf3c');
    },
    function() {
        $('body').css('background', '#d4e88f');
    }
);

$( "#jinfo" ).hover(
    function() {
        $('body').css('background', '#ff3c3c');
    },
    function() {
        $('body').css('background', '#d4e88f');
    }   
);

});
```

Comment: you should use .animate instead of .css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to have animation effect, also need to have [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)/[color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) library for background color animation to work

```
$("#jinfo").hover(function () {
    $('body').animate({
        'background-color': '#ff3c3c'
    });
}, function () {
    $('body').animate({
        'background-color': '#d4e88f'
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Xsnge/)